# existance of group with certain unique orders , 6 diferent ones

Tags: group-theory

Does there exist a group of 12 elements such that the orders of its elements are:
12; 12; 12; 12; 6; 6; 4; 4; 3; 3; 2; 1;

thought process: I know that order of an element g in a group is the least positive integer k such that $g^k$ is the identity

ok cool, now I want these elements, so im think maybe mod some multiple of 12 or 48 under multiplication? im unsure how to begin to search through. Any advice how to begin please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that since this group has an element of order $12$ and the group contains $12$ elements, the group must be cyclic. Now recall that if $d$ is a positive divisor of $n$, then the number of elements of order $d$ in a cyclic group of order $n$ is $\phi(d)$, where we use [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Indeed, observe that:

- $\phi(12) = 4$
- $\phi(6) = 2$
- $\phi(4) = 2$
- $\phi(3) = 2$
- $\phi(2) = 1$
- $\phi(1) = 1$

This is very promising! Indeed, consider the group $\mathbb Z_{12} = \{0,1,2,\ldots,11\}$ under addition modulo $12$. Observe that:

- $12 = |1| = |5| = |7| = |11|$
- $6 = |2| = |10|$
- $4 = |3| = |9|$
- $3 = |4| = |8|$
- $2 = |6|$
- $1 = |0|$

Comment: great! makes sense!! thanks