# Existance of group with certain unique orders

Tags: group-theory

> Does there exist a group of $12$ elements such that the orders of its elements are: $6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1$?

This is similar question to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676992/existance-of-group-with-certain-unique-orders-6-diferent-ones/677033#comment4442432_677033) where the group was cyclic since it had an element whose order was the same as the order of the group. There are so many $3$'s in this one that tells me that there cannot be such a group, but I don't know how to prove it - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be one of the elements of order $6$. Then $g^{-1}$ also has order $6$, so it must be the the other order-$6$ element, and they generate the same subgroup $N$, which must be normal (why?). The elements in this subgroup have orders 1,6,3,2,3,6, so all *other* elements in the group would have order $3$.

However the quotient $G/N$ has order $2$, so the canonical homomorphism into this quotient would map those order-$3$ elements into the non-identity element of $G/N$, which is absurd (why?).

Comment: Do I have to show the subgroup $N$ is invariant under conjugation by the elements of $G$? How do I do that since I do not know the elements of $G$? And how can this subgroup have $6$ orders and only $2$ elements? Can you please also explain the $G/N$ why it would have order $2$?

Comment: @JohnZobolas: You know (hopefully) that every conjugation takes an element to an element of the same order. So what does it do to $g$ and its powers? I'm not saying that anything "has 6 orders and only 2 elements" -- $g$ and $g^{-1}$ each _generate_ the subgroup I'm talking abou, but they're not its only elements.

Comment: I know that: if $y=h^{-1}xh$, then $o(y)=o(x)$. But I have to prove that  $\forall n \in N, g \in G: gng^{-1} \in N$. Your question does not help me understand further...

Comment: @JohnZobolas: Do I need to repeat myself? **Every conjugation takes an element to an element of the same order**. So where can the conjugation possibly take $g$?

Answer (score 3):

Well, a group of order $\;12\;$ *always* has a subgroup of order $\;4\;$ (why?), and thus it always has **either** an element (in fact, two) of order $\;4\;$ (why?) **or** at least two elements of order $\;two\;$ (why?)...

Comment: I know that there is a proposition that states that $g \in G, \text{ord}(g)=n, d|n, \text{ord}(g^{n/d})=d$, maybe it has to do with this or maybe Lagrange Theorem?

Comment: @JohnZobolas The claims referred to here use slightly more machinery than that. As an alterntive: Do you see that if such a group existed, it would have a normal subgroup of order $2$? What could the quotient look like?

Comment: I saw that: $o(g)=o(g^{-1})$, so I suppose I can create a normal subgroup taking the two elements that have order equal to $6$?

Comment: @JohnZobolas You're mentioning pretty basic and elementary results... Have you already studied Sylow theorems, or at least Cauchy's Theorem?

Comment: No! I will do now - I am actually learning through practise...

Comment: @JohnZobolas Fine, but then I think Henning's answer could be more appropiated for you at this level.

Comment: Yes and I understand that you try to be educative at the same time while answering and I appreciate that - it is just my low level that does not correspond to this!